# about counting sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I have read a counting sort algorithm which is like this:

```
Counting Sort(A[1,..n]) //C[1,...k] is the temporary memory and k is the range of integers
   for  i<-- 1 to k
      C[i]<-- 0
   for  j<-- 1 to n
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]+1
   for  i<--2 to k
      C[i]<--C[i]+C[i-1]
   for  j<--n downto 1
      B[C[A[j]]]<--A[j]
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]-1
```

I want to know that if I change the last for to this:`for j<--1 to n`  ,the algorithm will be correct too???(is there any way to show that with this "for" the algorithm will be correct??? )

also in this way the algorithm is stable too?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is correct both ways. It is also stable as you have it right now.

If you change the last `for` to what you said, it will stop being stable.

Basically, `C[i] = how many elements <= i exist` after the end of the third `for` loop. So `C[A[j]]` gives you the **the last** position of an element with value `A[j]` in sorted order, `C[A[j]] - 1` the **second last** position of an element with value `A[j]` and so on. This is why you decrement the values in `C`.

Because of this, you have to start iterating your original array in reverse order if you care about stability: so that the last element with value `x` in your original array gets put first in the new array. Iterating your original array in reverse will guarantee that `x` is put **after** all other values equal to `x`, thus making the algorithm stable.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, short explaination of the algorithm:

1. for loop: initialize the C array with 0 and the size k (the range of integers)
2. for loop: count the integer and store the number in C
3. for loop: sum up the total number of values less equal the given one
   Example: there are five 1, three 2, two 3 => c[1] = 5, c[2] = 8, c[3] = 10
4. for loop: starting at the end of the A array and putting it to the corresponding C value in the B value and decreasing the value in C

Because you store the last position for the different numbers in the C array, you have to start an the end of the A array, too. If you just work with integers the algorithm would also be correct if you start with j<--1 to n

stability is not given: e.g. the 1s would be in inverse order

Example: (I added indexes to the once, two show the order)

A[1a, 2, 1b]

first for loop

- C[1] = 0
- C[2] = 0

second for loop

j=1: A[1] = 1a

```
C[1] = 1
C[2] = 0
```

j=2: A[2]=2

```
C[1] = 1
C[2] = 1
```

j=3: A[3]=1b

```
C[1] = 2
C[2] = 1
```

third for loop

C[2] = 3

fourth for loop

j=1
     b[2]=1a
     c[1]=1

j=2
    b[3]=2
    c[2]=2

j=3
    b[1]=1b
    c[1]=0

Resulting:

- b[1] = 1b
- b[2] = 1a
- b[3] = 2

=> not stable

Comment: thanks with your short explanation and your example I get the whole

Comment: also is there any way to show that with this "for" the algorithm will be correct???

Comment: this is also stable see this link I have found it :

http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/tristan/CountPage.html

Comment: I hope, it don't loose the formatting. - Damn, it does - See my answer, I appended an example.

Comment: To your second comment, for sure there is a way to show, that with the other for loop, it is also correct. But it's to early and I have currently no clue, how I could do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm seems to be stable as it is to me.

If you change the last `for`, then it will still be correct, but won't be stable. (will reverse the order of equal elements).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `1 to n` would still sort correctly, but you'll use stability that `n downto 1` has.

After the second loop `C` contains the comulative sum, those values are exactly the indicies of the *last* element of each number in the final array. That's why going backwards gives stability.

You can get stability for `1 to n` too:

```
Counting Sort(A[1,..n]) //C[1,...k] is the temporary memory and k is the range of integers
   for  i<-- 1 to k
      C[i]<-- 0
   for  j<-- 1 to n
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]+1
   last <-- C[1]
   C[1] <-- 0
   for  i<--2 to k
      tmp <-- C[i]
      C[i]<--C[i-1]+last
      last <-- tmp
   for  j<--n downto 1
      B[C[A[j]]]<--A[j]
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]-1
```

the cumulative sum gets a bit ugly. But I'm sure this could be done nicer.

Comment: this is also stable see this link I have found it :

http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/tristan/CountPage.html