# changing counting sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, analysis

This is a counting sort algorithm.  I want to change the last `for` loop of it to `for j<---1 to n`.
I know that this will be correct, but I want to show this for one of my friends.  How can I write my reason for it?  Please help me!  Thanks.

```
Counting Sort(A[1,..n]) //C[1,...k] is the temporary memory and k is the range of integers
   for  i<-- 1 to k
      C[i]<-- 0
   for  j<-- 1 to n
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]+1
   for  i<--2 to k
      C[i]<--C[i]+C[i-1]
   for  j<--n downto 1
      B[C[A[j]]]<--A[j]
      C[A[j]]<--C[A[j]]-1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [about counting sort algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076037/about-counting-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code is absolutely correct. If you change the last loop from `1 to n` the output will be correct but the relative order of the elements with same values will get reversed. For e.g - If original array contains only 3 elements and all of them are let say 5 then in case of `1 to n`, the last five will be the first element, second last 5 will be the second element and the first 5 will be the last element i.e relative order of same elements got reversed.

Answer (score 1):

No, the last loop should be `n downto 1` as this results in the sort being a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (i.e. if two elements are equal, they will remain in their original order).

If you change it to `1 to n`, then all the equal subsequences of the list will be placed into the reverse order. Sometimes it doesn't matter, but sometimes it does, and since there's no disadvantage in using `n downto 1`, it should be preferred.

Comment: I think with this changing in the last for it will be stable to please see this link: 

http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.L.Mumford/tristan/CountPage.html

Comment: That page is inaccurate. Try it yourself!!